# Why does cluster_infomap in igraph R give different communities each time?

Tags: r, graph, cluster-analysis, igraph, network-analysis

I am using the cluster_infomap function from igraph in R to detect communities in a undirected, unweighted, network with ~19,000 edges, but I get a different number of communities each time I run the function. This is the code I am using:

```
   clusters <- list()
   clusters[["im"]] <- cluster_infomap(graph)
   membership_local_method <- membership(clusters[["im"]])
   length(unique(membership_local_method))
```

The result of the last line of code ranges from 805-837 in the tests I have performed. I tried using set.seed() in case it was an issue of random number generation, but this does not solve the problem.

My questions are (1) why do I get different communities each time, and (2) is there a way to make it stable?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to tell from the info provided - can you make a reproducible example that gives different results on each run?

Comment: Please hover over the R tag - it asks for a minimal reproducible example. [Here's a guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610); also look at the R help files (e.g. `?cluster_infomap`, _examples_ section) and answers of regular posters (click the R tag). After that, edit & improve your question accordingly. A good one usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data, code tries incl required packages - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session. *Why?* It makes it easier for all to follow and participate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cluster_infomap` (see `?igraph::cluster_infomap` for help) finds a

> community structure that minimizes the expected description length of
>   a random walker trajectory

Whenever you deal with random number generation, then you get different results on each run. Most of the time, you can override this by setting a seed using `set.seed` (see `?Random` for help) beforehand:

```
identical(cluster_infomap(g), cluster_infomap(g))
# [1] FALSE
identical({set.seed(1);cluster_infomap(g)},{set.seed(1);cluster_infomap(g)})
# [1] TRUE
```

or graphically:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(2)
g <- ba.game(150)
coords <- layout.auto(g)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

# without seed: different results
for (x in 1:2) {
  plot(
    cluster_infomap(g), 
    as.undirected(g), 
    layout=coords, 
    vertex.label = NA, 
    vertex.size = 5
  )
}

# with seed: equal results
for (x in 1:2) {
  set.seed(1)
  plot(
    cluster_infomap(g), 
    as.undirected(g), 
    layout=coords, 
    vertex.label = NA, 
    vertex.size = 5
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I see that I need to set.seed right before calling the cluster_infomap function. That solves the problem. Thanks!